# vector<char> to int vs. vector<wchar_t> to int

Tags: c++, type-conversion, fstream

So I had the following function:

```
template < typename T >
void SomeClass::ReadBinary(T& Res)
{
    size_t sBytesToRead = sizeof(T);

    Res = 0;
    std::vector<char> vcBuffer(sBytesToRead);
    m_Fstream.read(&vcBuffer[0], sBytesToRead);

    // tbd - use reintepert_cast 
    Res = reinterpret_cast<T>(&vcBuffer[0]);
}
```

where `m_Fstream` is `std::fstream`.

this function worked as expected. However when I changed `m_Fstream` to type `std::wfstream` and adjust the function a little:

```
template < typename T >
void SomeClass::ReadBinary(T& Res)
{
    size_t sBytesToRead = sizeof(T);

    Res = 0;
    std::vector<wchar_t> vcBuffer(sBytesToRead); // type of vector changed
    m_Fstream.read(&vcBuffer[0], sBytesToRead);

    // tbd - use reintepert_cast 
    Res = reinterpret_cast<T>(&vcBuffer[0]);
}
```

I get different result (meaning different int value for `Res`). I kinda expected to have issue here. reading bytes from the file is most likely different in both cases.

I'm a little lost and don't know how to resolve this. any idea?

#### Note

`T` is either: `uint8_t`, `uint16_t` & `uint32_t`

Comment: I don't know (yet) why the result is different, but why on earth are you using a vector of wchar_t? You are reading bytes. Also, what is T?

Comment: @n.m. Please, edify me. appreciate it.

Comment: Why use `vector`, use raw array, since the size of buffer is known at compile time.

Comment: that is correct. will change it. but still doesn't resolve my issue.

Comment: If T is a pointer type, you are returning an address of a locally managed variable. Once the function returns, the buffer is no more. Dereferencing the returned pointer is UB. If T is not a pointer, then you are converting an address to a non-address, which makes little sense.

Comment: @idanshmu - You keep saying "bytes", but this is not correct.  There is a difference between number of characters and number of bytes.  Streams read characters, not bytes.

Comment: @n.m. I edited the question. `T` is basically integer type

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So should I use C `FILE` or is it resolvable with streams?

Comment: @idanshmu  On a high-level, what is your real goal?  You cannot turn an array of one type into another by merely casting.  A `vector<char>` and a `vector<wchar_t>` are two different, unrelated types.   Also, vcBuffer is local, so accessing it when that function returns is invalid (as n.m already pointed out).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My goal is the read a sequence of 1,2 or 4 bytes from a binary file and convert them to integers. this goal was achieved where `m_Fstream` was of `fstream` type. I learned later on that the file has some Unicode strings in it so I changed `m_Fstream` type to `wfstream`. these change broke the integer conversion. this is what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: @idanshmu: iostreams are theoretically badly broken for binary data to begin with.  Congratulations, you've encountered a case where they are also broken in the real world.  Use something that gives you raw access to the bytes of the file, and do byte->character conversion (which needs an encoding specified) as a separate step, and only on strings.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie. Ok. agree. so just to clarify is _something that gives you raw access to the bytes of the file_ a C `FILE` object?

Comment: To reiterate, you are turning an address of a local buffer into an integer. This is (a) implementation defined and (b) makes no sense whatsoever. In particular, this does not accomplish what you are trying to do, namely, reading a binary value from a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read a binary value from a stream, you need this:

```
template < typename T >
void SomeClass::ReadBinary(T& Res)
{
    m_Fstream.read(&Res, sizeof(Res));
}
```

There is no need to allocate vectors of anything and no need to reinterpret cast anything.

This is for `std::fstream` only. Do not use `std::wfstream` for binary input, use only `std::fstream`. `sizeof(T)` might be odd but `sizeof(wchar_t)` might be even, so you cannot read the exact amount of bytes you need with a `wfstream`. If you are absolutely must use `std::wfstream` and you are absolutely sure `sizeof(T)` divides `sizeof(wchar_t)` you can try something like

```
    m_Fstream.read(&Res, sizeof(Res)/sizeof(decltype(m_Fstream)::char_type));
```

but I personally have never tried this.

Comment: This is not true. `m_Fstream` is of type `std::wfstream` where and [read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/basic_istream/read/) does not get any type.